Get sharepoint items, when the ID's are stored in an array
I have two separate Sharepoint list: Alerts and TaskQueue. The Alerts list has 2 fields: 'Title' (string) and 'array' (string), the TaskQueue has 'Title' (string) and 'ok' (boolean), see screenshot below.
I want to update the TaskQeue's list items' field 'ok' from FALSE to TRUE when the TaskQueue's list items ID  matches with the Alert's 'array' field.
There is a flow, which iterates the Alerts list, make some other actions and updates the TaskQueue list.
So, for the Alert list item, where Title = 'one', I want to update the list items from TaskQueue with 1, 2, 3 ID.
For Title = 'two' I want update the TaskQueue list items with ID = 2, 3
and so on.
The length of the arrays can vary, but there is always at least 1. (it is part of a bigger flow, the Alerts list items created based on the TaskQueue list items)

I think, I should use the length of the array and use the 'Do until' action, but I can't figure out how to iterate it.
If the the array has 2 elements, I could pick the first and and second element's value, than use an 'Update item' action, where the ID field could be this value.

upd: I've found a solution:

a 'Do until' container, where I compare a the length of the array with a variable (let it 'varCount')
a compose action, where I get the 'varCount'th element of the array


variables('varArray')?[variables('varCount')]


increment the varCount variable with 1
update the item, where the item ID is the output of the previous compose action


You should use the for each action if you want to loop through an array.

thank you, I found a solution via the "Do until" action. I've updated the original question.
